# How to list number of lines inside each file listed by the ls command?

Tags: bash, ls, wc

I am using the bash ls command as follows:

```
ls -S -l *usc*.vhd
```

This lists all the files that have the letters usc in its name and ends with .vhd extension. Now, I also need the output to print how many lines there are in each file. Is this possible in bash? I will need to use *wc* command of bash in some way but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find` with `exec` param instead of `ls` command:

```
find . -type f -name "*usc*.vhd" -exec wc -l {} \;
```

Comment: OK, now that this is giving me number of lines along with file name, how do I pipe this into sort command so they file with the most lines comes out at the top?

Comment: @quantum231, pipe it to `| sort -rn`

Comment: I am getting the result I need so this questions has been answered. So thanks for that. What does \; do? First I thought maybe I need to put sort in its place, but this is not required. I am able to put the pipe after the \;

Comment: `\;` (or `";"` or `';'`) just passes a literal semicolon to `find` so that it knows where your `-exec` ends. You have to escape it to prevent bash from treating it as bash syntax.